# Can endergonic reactions be exothermic?

Tags: thermodynamics

Pretty much the title. I've heard it said that no (see, e.g [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-an-exergonic-chemical-reaction-always-exothermic), answer by Lukas Schaedler).  To quote his argumentation:

> No. Exergonic reactions may be both exothermic or endothermic. Endergonic reactions are endothermic only.
>
> Endergonic and exergonic relate to changes in free energy (delta G), while endothermic and exothermic are related to changes in enthalpy (delta H).
>
> Gibb’s equation written in form of free energy (G), enthalpy (H) and entropy (S) changes:
>
> delta G = delta H - T . delta S
>
> Therefore, it’s possible for an exergonic reaction (delta G < 0; decrease in free energy) to be both exothermic (delta H < 0; heat is released) or endothermic (delta H > 0; heat is consumed). The second scenario may happen if :
>
> T . delta S > delta H
>
> On the other hand, endergonic reactions are endothermic only; delta H needs to be positive and greater than T . delta S in order to delta G > 0

But it's not really clear to me why. In particular, in the example given, why is $\Delta S \ge 0$ (which in my understanding would be necessary to force $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$ to be negative)?

Comment: Reactions with ΔG negative are simply non existant.

Comment: @Maurice - Huh? The definition of an endergonic reaction is one where $\Delta G^\circ > 0$. There are plenty of reactions where this is not the case.

Comment: @Damian Birchler:  Posts outside chemistry.se may move (or become defunct).  Thus, it is better to repost (within reason) the argumentation clearly labeled as a quotation (the `>` sign at the beginning of the line yields the vertical bar).

Comment: @Todd Minehardt. Challenge : Which reaction can you give as an example of ΔG° < 0 ?

Comment: @Maurice - Any spontaneous reaction? I mean, the answer to the OP's query is that "endergonic reactions are defined as those where $\Delta G^\circ > 0$." That's it. It's a definition.

Comment: @Todd Minehardt. Of course, all spontaneous reaction are those where ΔG° < 0. But the question was : Does it exist equation where ΔG° > 0 ? The answer is  NO ! No reaction are possible with ΔG° > 0, because these reactions would not be spontaneous. Or give me an example !

Comment: Equilibrium reactions go both ways at the same time and only one way can be spontaneous. // KNO3 dissolution is exergonic and endothermic. KNO3 crystallization is exothermic and endergonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who posted that answer on Quora was probably confused about the significance of $\Delta S$ as it relates to spontaneity. For isolated systems in general the sign of  $\Delta S$ (the change in the entropy of the *system*) is the relevant criterion determining whether a process is spontaneous, since the entropy of the surroundings remains constant, so changes in the entropy of the universe are limited to the system.

$\Delta G$ is of course the relevant criterion for constant temperature and pressure processes. When the change is negative (exergonic) the process is spontaneous. This places no constraints on $\Delta H$ other than that it should satisfy

$$\Delta H \le T\Delta S$$

which can be interpreted as meaning that changes in the entropy of the surroundings must more than compensate for any potential decrease in the entropy of the system: if the entropy of the system decreases (is negative) then the entropy change of the surroundings ($-\Delta H/T$) must be positive and greater than this in magnitude:

$$\Delta S_\textrm{surr} \ge -\Delta S$$

Freezing of any pure substance above its melting point is an example of a process that is not spontaneous but exothermic. By extension, the reverse is also true: melting of a substance above its freezing point is exergonic (spontaneous) yet requires an input of heat (endothermic).

Note also that $\Delta G^\circ$ determines the position of equilibrium since $\Delta G^\circ = -RT \log K_\textrm{eq}$, but does not suffice to say whether the reaction is spontaneous. For that you need to compute $\Delta G = \Delta G^\circ + RT \log Q$, that is you need information about the starting concentrations.

Comment: "Freezing above the melting point", can this be achieved? In the lab?

Comment: Should it have been "below its melting point"?

Comment: @DamianBirchler No, I imagine not. That was the point of the (endergonic) example, since the question was whether an exothermic process could be endergonic.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to get it now. "Endergonic/not spontaneous" means doesn't happen under the given conditions (temperature, pressure, concentrations, etc.), period. I think my confusion stemmed from the fact that I've always considered "the reaction" to be, e.g., A + B -> C. But it doesn't really make sense to say "A + B -> C" is (not) spontaneous, one would have to say "A + B -> C is not spontaneous at temperature T, pressure p and so forth". To summarize, any reaction is both exo- and endergonic - it depnds on the conditions (temperature, pressure, voltage, ...).

Comment: I've also learned from Wikipedia (can't recall the page anymore, though) that the plain "A + B -> C" would be called a "process", which only together with a range of conditions makes for a full "reaction". I.e. "process" and "conditions" = "reaction". I find this terminology helpful. I don't know, however, if it's widely shared.

Comment: A chemical reaction involves making/breaking bonds. A process is a more general term and includes phase transitions and just about anything else, for instance a piston working could be called a process. To be fair I have not looked up the authoritative definition of process but that is my past experience. It even has its own Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_process // Defining spontaneity of a reaction should include composition (starting and ending) and T, p. Yes, conditions can modify the extent of reaction.